# Colocar tag html no Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não consigo colocar a tag `<br>` do html no jquery.

```
$('#test').change(function(){
    $('#doenca_atual').val($('#doenca_atual').val()+" <br> "+$('#test option:selected').text());
});
```

Ao invés de pular a linha com o `<br>`, ele simplesmente coloco o `<br>` em modo texto

```
<br> Z98   Outr estados pos-cirurgicos <br> Z95   Presenca implantes enxertos cardiacos vasc
```

Teria que ficar assim

```
Z98   Outr estados pos-cirurgicos 
Z95   Presenca implantes enxertos cardiacos vasc
```

Comment: Mas o que é $('#doenca_atual')?? Um **input**, se for, não tem como dar quebra de linha neste elemento.

Comment: eh um textarea do html

Comment: textarea não aceita br você tem que trocar por contrabarra N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você dá a entender que está adicionando as opções a um `<textarea>`, a quebra de linha para esse elemento não é o `<br>`, mas sim o `\r\n`. Também não é necessário substituir todo o conteúdo, basta adicionar a nova seleção.

```js
$('#test').change(() => {

  let selecionado = $('#test option:selected');

  if (selecionado.val() != "")
    $('#doenca_atual').append(`${selecionado.text()}\r\n`);

  //remove o item da lista
  selecionado.remove();
  //retorna a seleção para o primeiro item
  $('#test').val("");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="">selecione</option>"
  <option value="doenca 1">doenca 1</option>
  <option value="doenca 1">doenca 2</option>
  <option value="doenca 1">doenca 3</option>
  <option value="doenca 1">doenca 4</option>
  <option value="doenca 1">doenca 5</option>
</select>
<br />
<textarea id="doenca_atual" rows="10"></textarea>
```